# Promise related

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-promise

1. I am making a travel advisor app. here i have made a getPlacesData function in index.js which fetch data from api return data which i recieve from app.js, i want to know that when i  print type of data it gives object, but i know that async function always return promise??
2. in app.js in useEffect where i have recieve that data there i have also console.log its type it gives object but i know .then return promise.

**index.js**

```
// axios is libary which helps us t make  call
import axios from "axios";
const URL =
  "https://travel-advisor.p.rapidapi.com/restaurants/list-in-boundary";
const options = {
  params: {
    bl_latitude: "11.847676",
    tr_latitude: "12.838442",
    bl_longitude: "109.095887",
    tr_longitude: "109.149359",
  },
  headers: {
    "X-RapidAPI-Key": "bb4974756dmsh0ecde312f187eb9p175b1djsn7eeab8063995",
    "X-RapidAPI-Host": "travel-advisor.p.rapidapi.com",
  },
};

export const getPlacesData =  async() => {
  try {

    const { data: { data } } =  await axios.get(URL, options);
    console.log("data:", data);
    console.log("data:", typeof(data));
    return data;//returns restaurant data

  } 
  catch (error) {

    console.log(error);

  }
};
```

**app.js**

```
import React,{useState,useEffect} from "react";
import { CssBaseline, Grid } from "@material-ui/core";
import { getPlacesData } from "./api";
import Header from "./components/Header/Header";
import List from "./components/List/List";
import Map from "./components/Map/Map";
import PlaceDetails from "./components/PlaceDetails/PlaceDetails";

const App = () => {
  const [places,setPlaces]=useState([]);
  useEffect(()=>{
    getPlacesData()
    .then((data)=>{//we use .then because getPlacesData is async
      console.log("appdata",data);
      console.log("appdata:", typeof(data));
      setPlaces(data);
    })
  },[])
  return (
    <>
      <CssBaseline />
      <Header />
      <Grid container spacing={3} style={{ width: "100%" }}>
        <Grid item xs={12} md={4}>
          <List />

        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={12} md={8}>
          <Map />

        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

I want to get rid of my confusion.

Comment: Your question is unclear and your questions title doesn't help either

Comment: in which part you feel that?

Comment: It returns a promise, but `.then()` gets the resolved value, not the promise.

Comment: From what I understand from your question you receive an object, which is exactly what you should receive. You need to access a key in the object to get the data. Without seeing the whole object I won't be able to tell you the exact key but you can try `console.log("appdata",data.data);` which is cliche

Comment: You never log the value returned by `.then()`.

Comment: when i console.log type of(data) in getPlacesData it gives object it should be promise in type

Comment: I believe it would no longer be a promise after de-structuring `const { data: { data } } =  await axios.get(URL, options);` but I may be wrong, if you want the promise you can try `const data =  await axios.get(URL, options);`

Comment: same,  it gives object

Comment: You should read about [Promises](https://javascript.info/promise-basics), there is no value in this question.

Comment: `.then()` method of a `Promise` is called once the promise has been `resolved`. If the promise is `rejected` then the first chained `catch()` clause is executed. Hence in you case you will always receive an resolved value i.e an `object` from api response. Have a look at this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vq7s0ae6/) to understand better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.then()` method of a Promise is called once the promise has been `resolved`. If the promise is `rejected` then the first chained `catch()` clause is executed.

Hence in you case you will always receive an `resolved` value i.e an `object` from api response.

```js
async function someTask() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve(1), 2000);
  })
}

async function someOtherTask() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => reject(0), 2500);
  })
}



someTask().then((val) => console.info('in then '+val))
someOtherTask().then((val) => console.log(val)).catch(err => console.info('in catch: ' + err));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can handle it with async await (the same way you are calling the API)

```
  const [places,setPlaces]=useState([]);
  useEffect(()=> {
    const getData = async () => {
        const data = await getPlacesData()
        setPlaces(data)
    }
   getData();
 },[])
```

Your issue might be due to API error. you are not returning any thing from your catch.

Either return an error from your catch or do this one